VBA for Data Validation between 2 sheets in 1 workbook
I am looking for what my best option would be to have data from sheet 1 column G checked against a table in sheet 2 to validate if the data entered in sheet 1 appears in the table and if the data is not present in the table the cell in sheet one needs to be highlighted in red with an error message. I have tried simply using Data Validation however it only works if the data is typed into the cell not when data is pasted into the cell from another spreadsheet (which will be mostly how the spreadsheet is populated).
I have played with VBA using XLookup, If then and else, Worksheet Function Match. I just can’t seem to get anything to work.
Any ideas would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance 

You can use match() or Vlookup() to check if something exists in  column, that can drive conditional formatting. If you gave some copiable example data then some of us would play.

Please share the details of the code you tried and describe the issue you are encountering.

If you paste a range from another sheet then that will overwrite your CF setup….

I have put the data to be checked in column A and the table with the correct values in column E both on sheet1.
Place the following code in a module:
Sub ValidateData()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim found As Range
    
    ' Define worksheets
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Define the range to check in Sheet1 (Column A)
    Set rng1 = ws1.Range("A1:A" & ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    ' Clear previous validation
    rng1.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    
    
    ' Loop through each cell in the range
    For Each cell In rng1
        ' Check if the cell value exists in the table on Sheet2
        Set found = ws2.Range("E:E").Find(What:=cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        
        ' If not found, highlight the cell
        If found Is Nothing Then
            cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Red color
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub

In order to fetch changes to your data, place this code in Sheet1:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        Call ValidateData
    End If
End Sub

To make sure all is ok - on load. Also make the validate sub run on worbook load. Place this in "ThisWorkbook".
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    
    Call ValidateData
End Sub

